# Maven Dependency Resolution Is Not Working Properly

Tags: maven

As far as i read top level depths should be chosen. But as you can see below second level is chosen. Am i missing something?

[image]

Comment: These are transitive dependencies: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies

Comment: @6ton, the question is not about the transitive dependencies, but about why the version in the transitive dependency trumped that in the original POM. It's because of the explicit version constraints that the `jersey-spring` specifies in its POM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it should have worked as per the `Dependency Mediation` [rules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies), but it doesn't, because of the constraints on the `jersey-spring.pom` (see [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-spring/1.19/jersey-spring-1.19.pom)).

The constraint allows only versions 2.5.2 thru 3 of `spring-core` to be used with itself.

`<spring25-release-version>[2.5.2,3)</spring25-release-version>`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring25-release-version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

If you know for certain that `4.1.7.RELEASE` of `spring-core` plays well with that `1.19` of `jersey-spring`, you can try "managing" the dependency and then use it normally like you did.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

`Dependency management` basically trumps all other means.